# Git - Unignore any folder located anywhere inside repository that recursively allows everything

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitignore

How to unignore folder with a particular name (e.g. Sync) that can be located anywhere inside the repository and Recursively allow everything inside it, violating every other rule of gitignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution proposed (`!/**/Sync/**/*`) would not work alone, because [**It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)

So if you have a `.gitignore` with:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

You must whitelist *folders* first (`!*/`) and then exclude files (`!**/Sync/**`, no need for `**/*`)

The end result would be a `.gitignore` like:

```
*
!.gitignore
!*/
!**/Sync/**
```

Don't forget to check with any file which `.gitignore` rule applies with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- aFile
```

Note: `/` would be needed (for `!**/Sync/**`) if you wanted to **anchor** the whitelist from the *top* of your repository.
If not, no `/` needed: this would be relative to wherever your `.gitignore` is).

From [`gitignore` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> If the pattern does not contain a slash `/`, Git treats it as a shell glob pattern and checks for a match against the pathname relative to the location of the `.gitignore` file (relative to the toplevel of the work tree if not from a `.gitignore` file).

Answer (score 1):

Update: In VONC's answer he is correct to mention about `!*/` and the slash in the beginning of the pattern.

Unignore folder with a particular name (e.g. Sync) that can be located anywhere inside the repository and recursively allow everything inside it, violating every other rule of gitignore:

Inside .gitignore add the following:

```
*
!.gitignore
!*/
!/**/Sync/**
```

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain the/ which is an anchor. Please consider accepting the right answer again

Comment: @Vonc Thanks for explaining the slash in the beginning, :)

Comment: Sure, that was missing indeed.